# Why $S_4 / V_4 \cong C_6 \Longleftrightarrow A_4 \leq V_4 $?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I've encountered this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267366/352213
and I couldn't see why does $S_4 / V_4 \cong C_6 \Longleftrightarrow A_4 \leq V_4 $ but I can't see why would one imply the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A_4$ has 12 elements the quotient of $S_4$ by a normal subgroup containing $A_4$ is either $C_2$ or the trivial group. Therefore the two statements are contradictory.